# Microsoft Outlook 2016 Crashing on Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with application error 1000

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, outlook-2016

I've been trying to troubleshoot an error message on our Server 2008 RDS farm for about 3 weeks now and I'm getting nowhere. Randomly Outlook 2016 crashes and freezes. Sometimes it recovers and the user can carry on with their work and other times it bombs and completely throws the user out of Outlook.
From what I can see it creates an event log id of 1000. [Application error 1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDQJp.png)

**Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.4966.1000, time stamp: 0x5e205f31
Faulting module name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.4966.1000, time stamp: 0x5e205f31
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000bd5aa0
Faulting process id: 0x7a00
Faulting application start time: 0x01d60c1f44f8c35d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
Report Id: e8ed2ff4-781a-11ea-85f0-005056a21772**

The servers are completely updated, I've reinstalled office, run registry cleaners. The only thing I haven't done is to remove office, run sfc /scan and reinstall office. 
The error is common with all 6 of the RDS servers so I'm reluctant to do that right now.
I'm In the middle of building our new RDS environment but it's been put on hold, for obvious reasons. Very frustrating! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have to ask: do you really need to be using an end of lifed (no support, no security patches) operating system for your RDS environment?

Comment: At the moment yes. Like I said I’m building the new environment but things changed with the pandemic. 
Do you have any suggestions?